# Grafana Integration with Identity Provider using openid connect and generic oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, grafana, openam, forgerock

I am trying to integrate forgerock openAM (Identity Provider) with grafana using generic oauth. I have mentioned the endpoints and all in the configuration.

It redirects to the openAM server and asks for login credentials, but after clicking on the allow button, it's showing a server side error.

grafana.log below:

```
t=2017-12-31T12:26:52+0530 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=302 remote_addr=192.168.1.153 time_ms=0 size=338 referer=http://grafana.oneeight.com:3000/login
t=2017-12-31T12:27:26+0530 lvl=eror msg="login.OAuthLogin(get info from generic_oauth)" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Error getting user info: {\"error_description\":\"The access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed, or invalid for other reasons.\",\"error\":\"invalid_token\"}"
t=2017-12-31T12:27:26+0530 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=500 remote_addr=192.168.1.153 time_ms=92 size=1147 referer="http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080/openam/oauth2/authorize?realm=Operators&access_type=online&client_id=operator_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgrafana.oneeight.com%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fgeneric_oauth&response_type=code&scope=uid+openid+profile&state=OpiuNzehHEqm0hq93ogfKoSG1%2FMJXtcrhPgDz22Glc0%3D"
t=2017-12-31T12:27:26+0530 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/public/css/fonts.min.css status=404 remote_addr=192.168.1.153 time_ms=1 size=11374 referer="http://grafana.oneeight.com:3000/login/generic_oauth?code=ae93d8c7-3349-4618-88d3-c7f31645e6ff&scope=uid%20openid%20profile&state=OpiuNzehHEqm0hq93ogfKoSG1%2FMJXtcrhPgDz22Glc0%3D"
t=2017-12-31T12:27:26+0530 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/public/build/grafana.dark.min.css status=404 remote_addr=192.168.1.153 time_ms=2 size=11374 referer="http://grafana.oneeight.com:3000/login/generic_oauth?code=ae93d8c7-3349-4618-88d3-c7f31645e6ff&scope=uid%20openid%20profile&state=OpiuNzehHEqm0hq93ogfKoSG1%2FMJXtcrhPgDz22Glc0%3D"
```

Can anyone please help to figure out the solution?

Here is set of logs from OpenAM when grafana tries to access user details

```
b8efbd7-768a-4038-af7f-cd2de423d285-12480","2018-01-02T06:09:25.965Z","AM-ACCESS-OUTCOME","eb8efbd7-768a-4038-af7f-cd2de423d285-12478","id=vipin,ou=user,o=operators,ou=services,dc=oneeight,dc=com","[""444b699c238b89d301""]","192.168.1.77","8080","192.168.1.153","51058",,,,"false","GET","http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080/openam/oauth2/authorize","{""realm"":[""Operators""],""access_type"":[""online""],""client_id"":[""operator_id""],""response_type"":[""code""],""scope"":[""uid%20openid%20profile""],""state"":[""qbHM3cXul897yzIMeK5rQD4TZicEzw5N22F%2FrS3E8ls%3D""]}","{""accept"":[""text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8""],""host"":[""openam13.oneeight.com:8080""],""referer"":[""http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080/openam/XUI/""],""upgrade-insecure-requests"":[""1""],""user-agent"":[""Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36""]}","{""JSESSIONID"":""9C5CF9FDE026ECFF31BD51935CC8E45D"",""amlbcookie"":""01"",""i18next"":""en-US""}",,"SUCCESSFUL",,,"10","MILLISECONDS","OAuth","/Operators"
"eb8efbd7-768a-4038-af7f-cd2de423d285-12483","2018-01-02T06:09:32.981Z","AM-ACCESS-OUTCOME","eb8efbd7-768a-4038-af7f-cd2de423d285-12481","id=vipin,ou=user,o=operators,ou=services,dc=oneeight,dc=com","[""444b699c238b89d301""]","192.168.1.77","8080","192.168.1.153","51058",,,,"false","POST","http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080/openam/oauth2/authorize","{""realm"":[""Operators""],""access_type"":[""online""],""client_id"":[""operator_id""],""response_type"":[""code""],""scope"":[""uid%20openid%20profile""],""state"":[""qbHM3cXul897yzIMeK5rQD4TZicEzw5N22F%2FrS3E8ls%3D""]}","{""accept"":[""text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8""],""host"":[""openam13.oneeight.com:8080""],""origin"":[""http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080""],""referer"":[""http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080/openam/oauth2/authorize?realm=Operators&access_type=online&client_id=operator_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgrafana.oneeight.com%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fgeneric_oauth&response_type=code&scope=uid%20openid%20profile&state=qbHM3cXul897yzIMeK5rQD4TZicEzw5N22F%2FrS3E8ls%3D""],""upgrade-insecure-requests"":[""1""],""user-agent"":[""Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36""]}","{""JSESSIONID"":""9C5CF9FDE026ECFF31BD51935CC8E45D"",""amlbcookie"":""01"",""i18next"":""en""}",,"SUCCESSFUL",,,"34","MILLISECONDS","OAuth","/Operators"
"eb8efbd7-768a-4038-af7f-cd2de423d285-12496","2018-01-02T06:09:33.221Z","AM-ACCESS-OUTCOME","eb8efbd7-768a-4038-af7f-cd2de423d285-12484","id=vipin,ou=user,o=operators,ou=services,dc=oneeight,dc=com","[""d02fa012-ddff-40a1-ba83-3de3de2e18d6"",""69b85d3a-7ee8-4f01-a259-0ae26bfec634""]","192.168.1.77","8080","192.168.1.148","57122",,,,"false","POST","http://openam13.oneeight.com:8080/openam/oauth2/access_token","{""realm"":[""Operators""]}","{""host"":[""openam13.oneeight.com:8080""],""user-agent"":[""Go-http-client/1.1""]}","{}",,"SUCCESSFUL",,"{""scope"":""uid openid profile"",""token_type"":""Bearer""}","216","MILLISECONDS","OAuth","/Operators"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of that error is `Error getting user info: {\"error_description\":\"The access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed, or invalid for other reasons.\",\"error\":\"invalid_token\"}`.  That indicates that grafana isn't able to get the user info from OpenAM because it's refusing the token.

The first thing I'd recommend would be to check the OpenAM logs and see whether it gives you any more information about why it rejected the token.  The other thing you may want to verify is that you have your scopes set up correctly in the grafana configuration, and that your `api_url` setting is correct.

Looking at the documentation, it seems like the configuration should be

```
scopes = openid email profile
auth_url = https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/oauth2/authorize
token_url = https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/oauth2/access_token
api_url = https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/oauth2/userinfo
```

Where `https://openam.example.com:8443` is the address of your OpenAM server.

Comment: Thanks For the consideration. The Configurations are made like the same which are defined in the grafana documentations.

Comment: If you edit your post, and indent the log lines by 4 spaces then they will show up in the post as formatted text, right now it's very difficult to decipher what's going on there.  It does look like your scopes are set to `uid openid profile`, that shouldn't be related to your current problem, but Grafana will need the email address of the user for login to work.

Comment: The issue got resolved. I have added email to the scope and changed API URL in the configuration and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you confirm that the URLs above are correct? If so I'd like to add them to the Grafana docs

Comment: Extremely sorry for late reply. This is what I have done in the grafana configuration file for the authentication. We need to mention the realm which we have created in open for API URL attribute in grafana.ini file       **auth_url = http://openam_url:8080/openam/oauth2/authorize?realm=Operators
token_url = http://openam_url:8080/openam/oauth2/access_token?realm=Operators
redirect_uri = http://grafana_url:3000/login/generic_oauth
api_url = http://openam_url:8080/openam/oauth2/userinfo?realm=Operators**